# Confused on the function of "r"(raw string characters)

Tags: python-3.x

Confused over the purpose of "r". As i understand it helps to read as a normal character than its usage as an escape character

I tried multiple codes as follows and all are giving the same output. This is making me confused on the real interpretation of "r". While i agree with first 3 lines of code.Fourth one is where im confused.

```
1.re.sub("n\'t", " not", " i am n't happy")
2.re.sub("n\'t", " not", " i am n\'t happy")
3.re.sub(r"n\'t", " not", " i am n\'t happy")
4.re.sub(r"n\'t", " not", " i am n't happy")
```

Result of all 4 above is :'

' i am  not happy'

```
import re

re.sub(r"n\'t", " not", " i am n't happy")
```

Given that i have used "r" i expected the backslash to be treated as a characters and not escape character

Actual Output
' i am  not happy'

Expected Output
' i am n't happy'

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that there are two layers of -escaping: in the string literal, and in the regex. And in neither does `\'` have a special meaning, and it's just treated as `'`.

What using `r""` does here is to skip the first string-literal escaping, so that a literal `\` is included in the string, but then the regex sees the string `\'` and just treats it as `'`.

So all four come down to replacing `n't` with `not`.

You still need *double* backslashes to match a literal backslash.